# Updating Json Object using data from a CSV File

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, file-handling

I have a JSON File (>1GB) and I have another CSV File with one matching column (i.e ID). I need to update the JSON File by mapping CSV with JSON.

The approach I thought at first was to convert the json to csv and then overwrite the csv, but since the file is huge, it's not the most optimized way. I am supposed to use Python.

```py
import csv           
import json

id = []
qrank = []

def readingCsvFile():
    with open('qrank.csv', 'r') as csvFile:
        dataCsv = csv.reader(csvFile)
        for row in dataCsv:
            id.append(row[0])
            qrank.append(row[1])

dataJson = [json.loads(line) for line in open('enhanced-wikipois','r', encoding='UTF-8')]

records = len(dataJson)

readingCsvFile()

for i in range(records):
    x = dataJson[i]['id']
    if (x in id):
        pos = id.index(x)
        dataJson[i]['wikiQRank'] = qrank[pos]

print(dataJson)
```

Comment: *have a JSON File (>1GB)* does it contain one humongous single structure xor it has e.g. one object per line?

Comment: One object per line

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Can you confirm that your file is actually JSONL? Do all the JSON structures contain the same keys?

Comment: I've updated the question with the code. @ViaTech

Comment: it's better in this case to post a testable fragments from both json and csv files

Comment: The code works for small dataset (testable fragments), but for huge data, the program keeps running for hours

Answer (score 0):

The size of the file is not really relevant. What's important is the number of JSON objects and the number of "qrank" values.

If you build a dictionary based on id and rank from the CSV file then the subsequent lookups will be much more efficient.

There are a number of other efficiencies that you could implement.

```
import csv
import json

CSVFILE = '/Volumes/G-Drive/qrank.csv'
JSONLFILE = '/Volumes/G-Drive/enhanced-wikipois'

def read_csv(filename):
    with open(filename, newline='') as data:
        reader = csv.reader(data)
        return {_id: rank for _id, rank, *_ in reader}

def read_jsonl(filename):
    with open(filename) as data:
        return [json.loads(line) for line in data]

id_dict = read_csv(CSVFILE)
json_data = read_jsonl(JSONLFILE)

for j in json_data:
    if (_id := j.get('id')) is not None:
        if (rank := id_dict.get(_id)) is not None:
            j['wikiQRank'] = rank

print(json_data)
```